# Trying to convert Perl to PHP

Tags: php, perl, md5, pack

I'm having trouble converting the following code from Perl to PHP. In particular, I'm having trouble with this section, as I have no clue what is happening here:

```
sub md5sum($) {
    my @ib = unpack("C*", shift);
    my $encstr = join("", map {sprintf('\%3.3o', $_)} @ib);
    my ($out) = split(/ /, `printf '$encstr' | md5sum`);
    return $out;
}
```

The main point I'm looking for help on is what does the `"C*", shift` do in the unpack statement, what's going on in the `join` part, and what does the `| md5sum` do at the end of the `split`

For this section below, I believe I'm also having trouble. My main question here is for the php pack, do I specify the H32, or just the H?

```
$hexchal = pack "H32", $challenge;
$newchal = pack "H32", md5sum($hexchal . $uamsecret);
my $passvar = "";
$passvar = md5sum("\0" . $password . $newchal);
```

Here is what I've tried for the section above, but the $hexchal's don't match up

```
$hexchal = pack("H32", $challenge);
$newchal = md5($hexchal.$uamsecret);
$passvar = md5("\0".$password.$newchal);
```

Answer (score 2):

Code looks a little confusing to me but here's my interpretation:

```
<1> sub md5sum($) {
<2>   my @ib = unpack("C*", shift);
<3>   my $encstr = join("", map {sprintf('\%3.3o', $_)} @ib);
<4>   my ($out) = split(/ /, `printf '$encstr' | md5sum`);
<5>   return $out;
    }
```

the `"C*", shift` on <2> converts the string into an array of numbers which is then joined together to form a new string by doing the sprintf formatting on each number. The resultant string is then used a aparameter when executing the command line `printf '$encstring' | md5sum` and the return is captured and returned. Effectively this returns with the md5sum ( as returned by the shell command ).

as an example calling the function with 'username' as a parameter will result in the command line being constructed as `printf '\165\163\145\162\156\141\155\145' | md5sum` which gives a result of `14c4b06b824ec593239362517f538b29  -` however if we drop the piped md5sum and just execute  `printf '\165\163\145\162\156\141\155\145'`  in a shell then we get the original string of 'username' returned.

It looks to me as though the only reason for the unpack,join and printf is to provide a little more security so processes do not contain the original string should somebody hack the machine and watch the processes etc.

The split on whitespace appears to be used to ommit the trailing - character returned by the command line call so that you only get the md5sum by splitting the retruned string from the command line into 2 values but only capturing the first into the returned $out scalar variable.

I assume that the author of the code could not use the CPAN MD5 module and so fell back to using the command line md5sum command but wanted to obfuscate and command line calls.

You should be able to replace the entire function with a php md5sum function call with just the string as the parameter ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php )

Comment: Re "the only reason for the unpack,join and printf is to provide a little more security", Maybe, but I think it's too allow arbitrary strings, include those that include single quotes and NULs. `printf '\047\000' | hexdump -C`

Comment: yes - that makes sense - the single quote would trash the command line - shouldn't be an issue that needs to be dealt with by translating the php to use the md5sum function but does provide a more likely interpretation of the original intent of the perl coder.

Comment: I apologize, I can see how that would be confusing, as it was to me when I was first looking at it. Fortunately the original coder had left comments to explain what the md5sum was there for. Apparently md5 wasn't working properly on the system (a network device) this was originally coded for, so they resorted to that md5sum method instead. Hope that clears things up!

Comment: Does this answer you question - if so could you please tick the box :^)

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code is obviously missing a call to `pack`. Try:

```
$hexchal = pack("H32", $challenge);
$newchal = pack("H32", md5($hexchal.$uamsecret));
$passvar = md5("\0".$password.$newchal);
```

Alternatively, you can set the `raw_output` parameter of PHP's `md5` function to `TRUE`:

```
$hexchal = pack("H32", $challenge);
$newchal = md5($hexchal.$uamsecret, TRUE);
$passvar = md5("\0".$password.$newchal);
```

You should use `"H32"` in PHP just like in Perl. It tells `pack` to expect 16 bytes (32 nibbles).

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I left out the () not sure how I missed that other than it was pretty late when I started toying with this again. Also thank you for the clarification on pack!