# Perl to exec a program with arguments containing "@"

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

Am a newbie in Perl and need help with a small problem

> Situation:

1. I have to execute a command line program through perl.
2. The arguments to this command line are email addresses
3. These email addresses are passed to me through another module.

> Problem:

I have written the code to create the argument list from these email addresses but am having problem in running exec().

NOTE: If I pass hardcoded strings with escaped "@" character to the exec() as command args,it works perfectly.

1. Sub creating cmd args map

   ```
   sub create_cmd_args {
       my($self, $msginfo) = @_;
       my @gd_args_msg  = ('--op1');
       my $mf = $msginfo->sender_smtp;
       $mf =~ s/@/\\@/ig; ## Tried escaping @, incorrect results.
       push @gd_args_msg, '-f="'.$mf.'"';

       for my $r (@{$msginfo->per_recip_data}) {
       my $recip = $r->recip_addr_smtp;
       $recip =~ s/@/\\@/ig; ## Tried escaping @, incorrect results.
       push @gd_args_msg, '-r="'.($recip).'"';
     }
     return @gd_args_msg;
   }
   ```
2. Sub that uses this args map to exec the program

   ```
   sub check {
     my($self, $msginfo) = @_;
     my $cmd = $g_command;
     my @cmd_args = create_cmd_args($self, $msginfo);
     exec($cmd, @cmd_args); ### ******* fails here
   }
   ```
3. Sample run:

   ```
   INPUT:
     sender_smtp: <ashish@isthisreal.com>
     receiver_smtp: <areyouarealperson@somedomain.com>
   ```

Could someone please guide me what is wrong here?

Comment: You may find the `quotemeta` function useful here. But it would be useful if you could print the contents of `@cmd_args` so we can see how the interpolation is breaking ,because we can't tell how the input is getting handled in your code.

Comment: Thanks for help. I shall try quotemeta also. The current debug output from dumper is perfect.  ---->  -f="<ashish@isthisreal.com>" -r="<areyouarealperson@somedomain.com>"

Comment: Please also note that I have not posted the whole code (also truncated subs) and just the relevant part as there are many more options that are being passed to the command line and much more stuff being done here. I have just posted what I thought was relevant here. Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: before exec command, simple print "$cmd  @cmd_args" and look it is ok. In this situation, you are not 100% sure all inputs to $cmd sare ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an argument to a command in the shell,

```
-f="<ashish@isthisreal.com>"
```

causes the the string

```
-f=<ashish@isthisreal.com>
```

to be passed to the program. Your program passes

```
-f="<ashish\@isthisreal.com>"
```

to the program. The problem isn't the `@`; the problem is the `"` and `\` you are adding.

```
my $mf = $msginfo->sender_smtp;
push @gd_args_msg, "-f=$mf";   # Assuming $mf is <ashish@isthisreal.com>
```

Comment: ikegami, If you are talking about--> $mf =~ s/@/\\@/ig; ## Tried escaping @, incorrect results, then I have already tried without it, the result is the same..

Comment: Right, removing the `s///` just removes your bad fix. You still need to solve the original problem. I explained what the problem is and how to fix it in my answer. Please reread.

Comment: Thanks again. unfortunately, the "<" & ">" characters in email addr create problem in bash, if they are not in quotes. Also, I tested with "-f=$mf", if I try to print it, "@isthsreal" is expanded to '' unless I escape it. Please lemme know if i am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Your `exec $cmd, LIST` runs `$cmd`, not bash.  No shell involved.  No need to protect special shell characters.  And no shell to apply the quotes and backslashes you're adding, so they're passed to `$cmd`.

Comment: Re "unfortunately, the "<" & ">" characters in email addr create problem in bash", You're not writing a shell command. The strings passed to `exec` are passed to the program, which isn't bash.

Comment: Re "Also, I tested with "-f=$mf", if I try to print it, "@isthsreal" is expanded to ''", That's not true. If the output of `"-f=$mf"` doesn't contain `@isthsreal`, then `$mf` didn't contain `@isthsreal` in the first place.

Comment: I made a small mistake in the question with exec (while writing sample prog). I am calling exec as exec {$cmd} ($cmd,@cmd_args); I read the documentation @ http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html and I think this is the reason what you mention above does not work. :( sorry again, but please ignore this error and guide.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. The two forms are equivalent when the array isn't empty. Curly form is safer

Comment: Thanks Again Ikegami for all the help. It turned out that the email addresses were marked as tainted by perl and so, the program failed. I never could read the error strings as the streams were closed. I simulated the environment exactly in my sample test program and then could find it. Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction. Maybe, put this solution also in your answer and I shall mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the post at [Trying to convert Perl to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921035/trying-to-convert-perl-to-php/32921873#32921873) and the code within the md5sum implementation that calls the command line you will see an approach that will save you from needing to worry about escaping characters.